# Is there a way to update RubyGems offline?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir

I am trying to install Ruby + WATIR to a Windows server which is in an isolated environment.  Typically I would run the ruby installer followed by these two commands:

1) gem update --system

2) gem install watir

This is as per the instuctions [here](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/install.html)

The server I am now trying to install to does not have internet connectivity.  This causes the commands above to fail.

*Is there a way I can download the update packages required and copy them to the server to install locally?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do gem install it will search the current directory before looking to the remote source. You must specify the version if you are installing a local gem (see [rubygems manual](http://www.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10#page33)).

```
gem install copland-0.2.0.gem
```

I'm sorry, I don't know a way to update the gem system offline without doing a [manual upgrade](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3#page13)

Comment: You know, the manual upgrade looks like that might suit my needs... I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: Although tedious to do the first time around, the manual upgrade works.

Comment: To download the gem first use `gem fetch copland -v=0.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

I usually use

```
gem unpack blah-1.1.1.gem
```

to unpack the gem into individual Ruby files.  Then you just need to make sure that directory is in your Ruby load path, and it's as good as a normal gem.